# не компилируется скрипт php в Geany

Tags: php

Когда нажимаю кнопку "Выполнить", появляется окно cmd "php" не является внутренней или внешней командой". Почему?

Comment: потому что php не установлен или имя его другое (например php5 или php-cli)

Comment: что значит не установлен? php.exe есть в папке xampp. но в описании программы написано, что она может компилировать php тоже. то как его еще устанавливать??

Comment: Ага. Значит винда. Добавьте папку с xampp в PATH - это самое простое решение.

Comment: в меню "Переменные среды" - "Системные переменные" - Path дописал С:\xampp\php.exe, но ошибка не исчезла. что не так?

Comment: Потому что нужно путь к папке, где php.exe лежит там писать, а не к исполнимому файлу. И иногда после этого перезагрузить комп.

Comment: Исправил. Теперь при запуске выдает php startup: unable to load dynamic library \xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_mysql.dll - не найден указанный модуль.

Comment: ну, теперь придется ещё php.ini поправить. 
`extension_dir = "C:\xampp\ext"`
Правда после этого может перестать работать сам xampp, но тут я уже не помогу.